# Create Entities and training phrases for values in functions for google action

Tags: actions-on-google

I have created a trivia game using the SDK, it takes user input and then compares it to a value in my DB to see if its correct.

At the moment, I am just passing a raw input variable through my conversation, this means that it regularly fails when it mishears the user since the exact string which was picked up is rarely == to the value in the DB.

Specifically I would like it to only pick up numbers, and for example realise that it must extract '10' , from a speech input of 'my answer is 10'.

```
  {
  "actions": [
    {
      "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
      "name": "MAIN",
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "welcome"
      },
      "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN"
      }
    },
    {
      "description": "response",
      "name": "Raw input",
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "rawInput"
      },
      "intent": {
        "name": "raw.input",
        "parameters": [{
          "name": "number",
          "type": "org.schema.type.Number"
        }],
        "trigger": {
          "queryPatterns":[
            "$org.schema.type.Number:number is the answer",
            "$org.schema.type.Number:number",
            "My answer is $org.schema.type.Number:number"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "conversations": {
    "welcome": {
      "name": "welcome",
      "url": "https://us-central1-triviagame",
      "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
    },
    "rawInput": {
      "name": "rawInput",
      "url": "https://us-central1-triviagame",
      "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
    }
  }
}

app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', (conv) => {
  conv.data.answers = answersArr;
  conv.data.questions = questionsArr;
  conv.data.counter = answersArr.length;
  var thisQuestion = conv.data.questions;
  conv.ask((conv.data.answers)[0]));
});

app.intent('raw.input', (conv, input) => {

if(input == ((conv.data.answers)[0])){


       conv.ask(nextQuestion());
}


app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv,input) => {
 //verifying if input and db value are equal
// at the moment input is equal to 'my number is 10' (for example) instead of '10'

//therefore the string verification never works
conv.ask(nextQuestion());

});
```

In a previous project i used the dialogflow UI and I used this @system.entities number parameter along with creating some training phrases so it understands different speech patterns.

This `input` parameter I am passing through my `conv` , is only a raw string where I'd like it to be filtered using some sort of entity schema.

How do I create the same effect of training phrases/entities using the JSON file?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using Actions SDK instead of Dialogflow for this project? With Dialogflow you get to take advantage of the ML to better match potential entities, whereas with Actions SDK you would need to do that yourself.

Comment: I'd rather do everything in my IDE as opposed to hopping between the web UI and my IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this using just the Action SDK. You need a Natural Language Processing system (such as Dialogflow) to handle this as well. The Action SDK, by itself, will do speech-to-text, and will use the actions.json configuration to help shape how to interpret the text. But it will only return the entire text from the user - it will not try to determine how it might match an Intent, nor what parameters may exist in it.

To do that, you need an NLP/NLU system. You don't need to use Dialogflow, but you will need something that does the parsing. Trying to do it with simple pattern matching or regular expressions will lead to nightmares - find a good system to do it.

If you want to stick to things you can edit yourself, Dialogflow does allow you to download its configuration files (they're just JSON), edit them, and update or replace the configuration through the UI or an API.

Comment: Thanks, I just posted the a similar question but I imagine the response is exactly the same as this one! I have noticed that when downloading the JSONs from other projects, theyre split up into each individual intent, does that mean I need to run this `gactions update --action_package eachfile.json --project projectID` for every json i have?

Comment: I assume you mean "when [you] download the JSONs from Dialogflow projects'. The Dialogflow JSON format is different than the actions.json for the Action SDK. You would not use `gactions` to update based on them. My point was simply that if you want to edit the configuration - you can edit Dialogflow configuration, you don't need to use the web UI.